Как связать звук с контроллером громкости на сайте
Хочу внедрить на сайт фоновую музыку. Хотелось бы, чтобы пользователь мог управлять только громкостью, музыку залупить. Есть код контроллера уровня громкости звука. Но я пока не особо разбираюсь, как привязать к нему саму музыку?
codepen.io


var controlBox = document.getElementsByClassName("control-box")[0];
var volumeControl = controlBox.querySelector(".volume-control");
var volumeInput = volumeControl.querySelector("input[type=range]");

function setBars() {
  var volume = parseInt(volumeInput.value);
  volumeControl.className = "volume-control";

  if (volume > 0) {
    controlBox.classList.add("volume-on");
    volumeControl.classList.add("volume-" + volume);
  } else {
    controlBox.classList.remove("volume-on");
  }
}

volumeInput.addEventListener("input", setBars);
setBars();
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

.volume-control {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.volume-control .bars {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 80%;
}

.volume-control .bars .bar {
  width: 14%;
  margin: 0 7%;
  background-color: #bbb;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

.volume-control .bars .bar:nth-child(1) {
  height: 100%;
}

.volume-control .bars .bar:nth-child(2) {
  height: 100%;
}

.volume-control .bars .bar:nth-child(3) {
  height: 100%;
}

.volume-control .bars .bar:nth-child(4) {
  height: 100%;
}

.volume-control .bars .bar:nth-child(5) {
  height: 100%;
}

.volume-control .bars input[type=range] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10%;
  width: 110%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}

.volume-control.volume-20 .bars .bar:nth-child(1),
.volume-control.volume-40 .bars .bar:nth-child(1),
.volume-control.volume-60 .bars .bar:nth-child(1),
.volume-control.volume-80 .bars .bar:nth-child(1),
.volume-control.volume-100 .bars .bar:nth-child(1),
.volume-control.volume-40 .bars .bar:nth-child(2),
.volume-control.volume-60 .bars .bar:nth-child(2),
.volume-control.volume-80 .bars .bar:nth-child(2),
.volume-control.volume-100 .bars .bar:nth-child(2),
.volume-control.volume-60 .bars .bar:nth-child(3),
.volume-control.volume-80 .bars .bar:nth-child(3),
.volume-control.volume-100 .bars .bar:nth-child(3),
.volume-control.volume-80 .bars .bar:nth-child(4),
.volume-control.volume-100 .bars .bar:nth-child(4),
.volume-control.volume-100 .bars .bar:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: #000000;
}
<div class="control-box">


  <div class="volume-control">
    <source src="ark.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    <div class="bars">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="20" value="0">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Больше по части фриланса, но сегодня чуть позже помогу.

Чтобы прикрутить музыку, нужно тег source обернуть тегами audio:
<audio>
<source src="ark.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
</audio>

А в начале JS-кода добавть это:
const audio = document.querySelector("audio");

Регулировку громкости прикрутить так, как в первом ответе и главное запустить воспроизведение командой audio.play() повесив её на какое-то событие.

Так как значение audio.volume от 0 до 1  а у тя от  min="0" до max="100"  надо  volumeInput.value * 0.01
замени это
volumeInput.addEventListener("input", setBars);

на это
 volumeInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
            audio.volume = volumeInput.value * 0.01
            setBars()
        });

